# Getting "attribute" value in CakePHP(alternative of "attr()")

Tags: jquery, cakephp, attr

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. I need to convert this into `CakePHP code` :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".clickableRow").click(function(){
        window.document.location=$(this).attr("data-href");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Actually, I've already converted most of the code, I am just looking the alternative of the `attr()` function.

What I've done so far is :

```
<?php $this->Js->get('.selector')->event('click',$this->Js->redirect(---------));?>
```

So, do you guys have any idea about it ? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to convert it, you can use the original code.

Comment: Yes, I was actually using this original code, but recently I got a problem, that's why I am now trying to change it. @NickZinger

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way, but I have posted a possible solution. If you tell us what the actual problem is we might be able to fix that.

Comment: Yeah, I also think so. Ok, I'll post my actual problem here. @NickZinger

Comment: Fix your jquery code instead of trying to generate it with JsHelper. JsHelper can be quite limited in the code it can generate. Which is why it's removed in CakePHP 3.0

Comment: Hmm, got it :) @ADmad

Answer (score 0):

Just put your javascript/jQuery code as the 2nd parameter for event():

```
<?php
$this->Js->get('.selector')->event('click','window.document.location=$(this).attr("data-href");');
?>
```